# Calling class with javascript - nothing happens

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm bulding a star rating system with javascript. I'm trying to access a class name within a php page. Ideally it should cause the star to change colour on mouseover, but nothing is happening when I do.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    // put all your jQuery goodness in here.



                            $(function(){
                $('.star').mouseover(function (){
                    var star = $(this).index() 1;
                    $(this).parent().css("background-position","0 -" (32 * star) "px");
                });

                $('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
                    var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
                    $(this).css("background-position","0 -" (32 * originalresult) "px");
                });
            });​
});
```

html:

```
<div class="star-rating" id="rating1result0">
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
    <div class="star"></div>
</div>
<div class="result">
    <span style="color:green">0</span> (0)
</div>
```

Comment: I'd include the framework in your tags... this looks like jquery.

Comment: [JSHint only reports 20 errors, fix those then try again](http://www.jshint.com/reports/184129)

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/2p98h/1/

Try this, you had some syntax errors.  It's hard to test without the background.  Take a look at the code a make revisions as necessary.

Comment: @BrianByrne Check the jsfiddle link, let me know what you think.

Answer (score 0):

When updating css with jquery use `backgroundPosition` instead of `background-position`. It applies to every css command.

Comment: That's valid for object mode. In string you can do background-position or backgroundPosition.

Answer (score 0):

```
$('.star').mouseover(function (){
            var star = $(this).index() 1;
            $(this).parent().css("backgroundPosition","0 -" + (32 * star) + "px");
            });

            $('.star-rating').mouseout(function (){
            var originalresult = $(this).attr('id').split('result')[1];
            $(this).css("backgroundPosition","0 -" + (32 * originalresult) + "px");
           });
```

You need to add '+' when forming a string, and background-position should be backgroundPosition.

Answer (score 0):

after looking at the fiddle and adding the css with image it worked like it's supposed to. i did notice when you try and add this server side for some reason i kept getting extra chars even when i copy and pasted to notepad from fiddle and then into my document it didn't appear to have any extra spaces or characters but once it was on the server i was getting 3 extra chars at the end of the jquery code. i edited the file on the server removing the 3 extra chars used the code provided in the fiddle and it worked great. maybe just a bug on my end but that maybe what your experiencing.

http://jsfiddle.net/eviljackson/rwK3w/ - new fiddle with working example

hope this helps you as your post helped me figure out the issue on my end have a good one... css is below so it's included in this thread

the css

```
    .star-rating {
     width:80px;
     height:16px;
     float:left;
     background:url(http://i39.tinypic.com/2cntjsl.png);
     cursor:pointer;
     }
     .star {
     width:16px;
     height:16px;
     float:left;
     }
     .result {
     float:left;
     height:16px;
     color:#454545;
     margin-left:5px;
     line-height:110%;
     }
```